# Поиск простого числа в функциональном стиле в Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно найти все простые числа на отрезке [2:n], n - вводится пользователем. Все бы ничего, но требуется написать программу в функциональном стиле (без циклов, переменных и условных операторов)

Comment: А компьютером можно пользоваться? А если серьезно, как вы собираетесь обрабатывать последовательность чисел на заданном отрезке без явного (`for`) или неявного (`map`, `list comprehension`) цикла?

Comment: я могу себе представить решение без циклов, но как сделать это без условных операторов???

Comment: map и list comprehension пользоваться можно, нельзя: if, else, for, while. Возможно я немного не правильно выразился.

Answer (score 1):

Решение взято [отсюда](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0#Python_3.x):

```
def eratosthenes(n):
    return [x for x in range(2, n)
            if x not in [i for sub in [range(2 * j, n, j)
                                       for j in range(2, n // 2)] 
                         for i in sub]]
```

Пример:

```
print(eratosthenes(50))
#[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]
```